# ARRAY_SUM with condition

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have document like this

```
    {
        bills: [
             { 
                  id: "1",
                  total: 20.0
              },
              { 
                  id: "1",
                  total: 20.0
              },
              { 
                  id: "2",
                  total: 10.0
              }
         ]
    }
```

I would like to do the DISTINCT SUM of total value with distinction based on id property but could not find and instruction for this case.

For the example case, the expected total is 30.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one you choose when “id”:“1” has different values

```
{
     bills: [
          { 
               id: "1",
              total: 20.0
          },
          { 
               id: "1",
              total: 30.0
          },
          { 
               id: "2",
              total: 10.0
          }
    ]
}
```

By using subquery expression https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/subqueries.html you can use complete select functionality of arrays.

In case of different values the following query uses MAX. This is per document sum

```
SELECT  ARRAY_SUM((SELECT RAW MAX(b.total) FROM d.bills AS b GROUP BY b.id)) AS s
FROM default AS d
WHERE ......
```

Comment: This is brilliant and looks like an answer to me! I will try and let you know! To your answer the total values are the same (there are other properties which are not the same)

Answer (score 2):

Use the ARRAY operator to select which elements of the array you want to use.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#array

Then use ARRAY_DISTINCT() and ARRAY_SUM() to compute the total.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-distinct
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-sum

Comment: The point is to select which elements to use, the elements are pretty much the same on the selection criteria. The ARRAY_DISTINCT works on basic data type and not object.

Comment: ARRAY_DISTINCT() works on any data type, In case of OBJECT if single character is different in field or value it is different. In case of ARRAY position also matters. If these functions doesn't solve use subquery expression  as SELECT you can use any feature in the query

Comment: @vsr let me try the ARRAY_DISTINCT (again) on the object because it looks like better solution

Comment: the ARRAY_DISTINCT works with object (my previous try failed because I gave different total value), but the document on Couchbase site should be giving more example on this case ...